# Correct approach for predicting new value based on similarity to other data points

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, interpolation

relative rookie here so apologies if the answer to this is obvious.

I am trying to find the correct approach/technique for this problem.

I have object A and a data set. The data set contains 2 columns, a score representing how similar object A is to 10 other objects and a value for all other objects - something like this:

| Object | Similarity | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 0.9 | 95 |
| C | 0.85 | 97 |
| D | 0.73 | 86 |
| E | 0.6 | 75 |
| F | 0.5 | 81 |
| G | 0.45 | 60 |
| H | 0.2 | 32 |
| I | 0.05 | 18 |

Object A is very similar to object B (which has a value of 95) - but very dissimilar to object B (which has a value of 18).

I am trying to predict what the value of object A will be given the value and similarity of the other objects.

This feels like something that should have a straightforward approach but I can't figure out what it is.

Any help or suggestions welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! This sounds like a k-nearest neighbors type of problem. You might have some luck reading about that technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds very much like [$k$-nearest neighbor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm). Essentially, pick the $k$ nearest (in your case: most similar) objects and use the average of their scores as your prediction. You could even weight their scores by similarity, but that does not always improve matters.

Find the best $k$ through [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)).

Comment: Hi Stephan, thank you for your response. How would I then make a prediction of the value for object A if I don't have a similarity score for that object?

Comment: You don't need a similarity score of an object to itself, only similarities to objects whose score you do know. It's just like the standard k-NN algorithm, where you don't need the distance of an object to itself, only to others.

Comment: Great, thanks. How would I implement that in python? I believe scikit learn's KNeighborsClassifier() will only accept an X and Y argument - do you know of a similar function which will group univariate data?

Comment: Hm. I think you would need to code this yourself. It shouldn't be too hard to calculate an index that extracts the $k$ objects with the highest similarity.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try. Thanks for your help